No value provided for parameter `container_name` in the Get Metadata1 activity

I have added the Linked Service and Dataset pointing to blob storage account.
But I don't know what should I give the container_name parameter value to copy all the containers.
So, when I define the Get Metadata activity to list all the containers dynamically, it is asking me to provide the value of the container_name in the dataset properties:

If I provide * as a value, it is not accepting. Then what will be the value of that parameter?

It seems like you are using the same source dataset which you have given for copy activity, in the Get meta data activity as well.
To list the container names using Get meta data activity, you should not give any path in the dataset. But copy activity inside For-each activity requires a parameterized source dataset for the dynamic container names. So, you cannot use the same source dataset that you are using for copy activity for the Get meta data activity.
You need to create another source dataset for the Get meta data activity and leave path as it is and no need to create parameters for the containers in this dataset.

Now, give the ChildItems property in the Get meta data activity.

After debugging, now you can see it is giving the expected container names as a list.

So, the total datasets in your scenario should be 3. Two parameterized datasets for the copy activity source and sink and one non-parameterized source dataset for the Get meta data activity.
